# Silverlight - RIA Services - get insert ID

Tags: c#, silverlight, insert, ria

I am using RIA services in my Silverlight Application the following is the code generated by Visual Studio 2010,

```
public void InsertDiscussion_topic(discussion_topic discussion_topic)
{
    if ((discussion_topic.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
    {
        this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(discussion_topic, EntityState.Added);
    }
    else
    {
        this.ObjectContext.discussion_topics.AddObject(discussion_topic);
    }
}
```

now this doesn't return the inserted ID how do i get the inserted ID?

thank you for all the help!!!

Comment: Are you calling save changes?

Comment: Is this client-side generated RIA code ? Please show us the service implementation

Answer (score 2):

If you use WCF RIa Services, you Id will automatically updated after DataContext.SubmitChanges()

```
MyEntity ent = new MyEntity(); //entity that has Id, mapped 
//from primary key (Identity) from data base

MyDataContext.MyEntities.Add(ent);
MyDataContext.SubmitChanges(op => { if (!op.HasError) MessageBox.Show(ent.Id.ToString()); });
```